# I have changed my system and have installed windows 10.In new system I can't open my unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have changed my system and installed Windows 10.

In new system I have installed the same version of unity and all related software and plug-ins needed to run my project.

But When I open my project it show me splash screen of unity load project for some seconds after that it breaks. Project is not opening. I couldn't understand why is this so.
Current version of unity which I am using is Unity 2021.1.25f1 and my project is connect with plastic SCM.

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build.  Net uses windows dlls and changing window version requires all the code to get recompiled.

Comment: Close Unity, delete the **Library** folder (which is essentially a cache) and try opening your Unity project again.